# Website multilingual based on URL Folder and PHP Gettext

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, multilingual

I set up PHP to use Gettext and translate my website /index.php based on the language.

Now I would like to have the URL different for each language ( example: mydomain.com/fr/ ). But each folder should point to the main directory and PHP will change the language depending from which URL the user is using ( mydomain.com/fr/ or mydomain.com/it/ ).

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What exact part are you stuck with? The mechanics of URL rewriting depend a lot on the web server software and the routing abilities of your PHP code.

Comment: I just don't know where to start. An idea should be to rewrite mydomain.com/fr/ to mydomain.com/&lang=fr and then set the language in the PHP file depending on the lang variable. Is that a good way ?

Comment: A usual approach is to have a library like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) for the routing part and a middleware layer to process session language. But I suspect all you have so far is a collection of public "*.php" files with PHP code embedded in HTML—that makes the overall question too broad to get properly answered here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have a rewrite mod to rewrite any .php to .html

Should I just do an URL REWRITING ?

Rewrite any mydomain.com/par1/par2.html to mydomain.com/par2.php/&lang=par1 ?

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not working at all

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html $1.php\?lang=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

It is only up to your imagination (and your regex skills :-B but even I got it and my regex skills are rather weak.)

You could do [www.mysite.com/articoli/Sed_ut_perspiciatis_unde_omnis/4711/](http://www.mysite.com/articoli/Sed_ut_perspiciatis_unde_omnis/4711/) for the italian article
and
[www.mysite.com/articles/far_far_way_behind_the_word_mountains/4711/](http://www.mysite.com/articles/far_far_way_behind_the_word_mountains/4711/)  for the english version of the same article (product)

and you rewrite the first to
[www.mysite.com/article.php?lang=it?article_id=4711](http://www.mysite.com/article.php?lang=it?article_id=4711)
and the second to
[www.mysite.com/article.php?lang=en?article_id=4711](http://www.mysite.com/article.php?lang=en?article_id=4711)
(The middle part is discarded - look at ebay ads other pages with categories - they do it like this )

Takes you two regexp rewrites.

Basically you have to think about a structure logical to SEO and intuitive for users wgo sees the url.

This depends also on: what are the most visited pages of your site?
I have eg. only 1 php script/page which is responsible for 90% of all web traffic.
It used to be 2 (one per german and 1 in english but now I have it "gettext'ed" and now its only one page so much less maintenance.

If SEO optimization is interesting for you - look at similar well known pages and their page /URL structure.

Only rewriting mysite.com/fr/bubalu.html to  mysite.com/bubalu.php?lang=fr will be useful only if you have very few pages and I ask myself if this really explains your site structure best to crawlers..